# Am I allowed to ask for a rep boost?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I asked a question with a bounty and didn't realize I would loose the ability to comment.  Can I get a few up votes to get enough reputation back please?  I've seen this done on other meta sites so I hope this wont be a problem

Too bad once you give up reputation for a bounty you loose privleges with it.  Would it be possible to make things like commenting more perminent?  Like once you get the ability you keep it so long as its not down votes resposible for the reputation loss.

Comment: I gave you an upvote on an answer, but that was because it was a good answer. :)

Comment: I'm a bit confuzed as to why these 3 upvotes hasn't given me any reputation.

Comment: Upvotes on meta don't count toward your rep score - only votes on the "real" (not meta) site will affect your rep score.

Answer (score 7):

Given the nature of the site - Quality Questions and Answers - just simply up-voting for the sake of up-voting is typically discouraged. Not that anyone of your questions/answers isn't good, but it should be up-voted based on merit/quality - not by request.

You're at a rep of 33 now, you're 17 points away from being able to comment again. I'm sure you can find a few [Unanswered Questions](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered) which could use some attention - or possibly [Ask a Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) yourself!

Comment: I bet those 17 points will take a while for me to pick up.  I usually spend time looking for an answer before asking any questions so I don't end up asking many questions, on any SE/SO site.  Also ubuntu isn't exactly my strongest subject so I guess I'll have to wait a bit before I can comment, or post comments as answers for a bit.

Comment: @WalterJ89 if you get 200 rep on any other StackExchange site, you get 100 rep on all others. This only happens once.