# How is reputation shared between Meta and Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

I have been floating around on Meta occasionally, but most of the time is spent on Ask Ubuntu. When I receive upvotes or accepts on Meta, it says that I gain reputation, but it does not seem to affect my overall reputation score. Is there a specific way in which rep is shared between the two sites? Or is reputation simply not gain from Meta? Or is there two different scores, and whichever one is highest is displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered my own question when I was browsing around Meta. According to [Torbengb's comment here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/305/am-i-allowed-to-ask-for-a-rep-boost) upvotes on Meta do not count towards your reputation score.

The link in the comment below by fluteflute has a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true...

Comment: If someone posts an answer that is more accurate than mine then I will happily accept it. I am kinda just going off of a comment.

Comment: It seems Torengb was correct, here is [a far more detailed explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64267/is-there-a-reason-why-we-gain-ghost-reputation-on-the-meta-of-an-se-website/64268#64268).